# Using extra options in single products page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

i am running a Woman cloths website in wordpress woocommerce variable products.

Now we need to addons(checkbox) we want in checkbox there is a type of inventory stock management
Example if some one buy small pret then there is a check box of Small Pant that we have added price and inventory of small pant

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your message is you want to give a size option to your customer.
Products with different sizes have different inventory and prices.

All you have to do is, create your products with different variations (Small, Medium, Large) or colors (Red, Blue, Green).

You can also check this blog post for a better understanding.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Also, explore this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/

Comment: Hi Danish, Thanks for your help. but at last i find there is  a bug in my theme that not accepting any plugins. That's why i change complete theme of the website.